# Foreign Key Failure #1452 MariaDB PhpMyAdmin Mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

got a slight problem with my constraint I wanna add to my tables:

so first at all my tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Sales`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sales` (
  `ItemNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Model` varchar(100) NOT NULL unique,
  `PurchasingPrice` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `ManufNo` int(11) Not Null,
  `LocNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SuppNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CatNo`int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UnitPrice`decimal (11,2),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ItemNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `Sales` (`ItemNo`, `Model`, `PurchasingPrice`,`ManufNo`, `LocNo`,`SuppNo`,`CatNo`,`Unitprice`) VALUES
(1,'Tieflader 18t',6969.84,4,1,6,2,9582.56),
(2,'Betonmischer-3m³',47829.00,3,2,3,3,82457.23),
(3,'Lastenkran 800kg',4129.00,2,2,2,3,8466.43),
(4,'Hubwagen,10m',9478.00,1,2,3,3,18457.84);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Rent`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Rent` (
  `ItemNo` int(11) NOT NULL, ( Different Number-Area like 1000+, very small project)
  `Model` varchar(100) NOT NULL unique,
  `PurchasingPrice` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `ManufNo` int(11) Not Null,
  `LocNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SuppNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CatNo`int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PricePerDay`decimal (11,2),
  `RentDateNo`int(11),
  `AdressNo` int(11),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ItemNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `RENT` (`ItemNo`, `Model`, `PurchasingPrice`,`ManufNo`, `LocNo`,`SuppNo`,`CatNo`,`PricePerDay`,`RentDateNo`,`AdressNo`) VALUES
(1000,'Betonmischer 50l',123.45,4,1,6,2,42.56,2,1),
(1001,'Winkelschleifer 800 Watt³',29.00,3,2,3,3,17.23,3,1),
(1002,'Akkuschrauber 12V',129.00,2,2,2,3,16.43,1,2),
(1003,'Akkuschrauber 18V',178.00,1,2,3,3,21.84,1,2);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Stock`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Stock` (
  `ItemNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Min-Stock` int(11) Not Null,
`Current-Stock` int(11) Not Null,
`Max-Stock` int(11) Not Null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ItemNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `Stock` (`ItemNo`,`Min-Stock`,`Current-Stock`,`Max-Stock`) VALUES
(1000,0,1,1),
(1001,0,1,1),
(1002,0,0,1),
(1003,0,1,1),
(1,2,5,8),
(2,1,2,2),
(3,3,6,9),
(4,1,3,4);
```

When I try to add an constraint FK with:

```
ALTER TABLE `Stock`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sales_stock_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemNo`) REFERENCES `sales`(`ItemNo`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `rent_stock_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemNo`) REFERENCES `rent`(`ItemNo`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

it does Fail. When I delete all Numbers which aren't from the sales Table I can use this one:

```
ALTER TABLE `Stock`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `sales_stock_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ItemNo`) REFERENCES `sales`(`ItemNo`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

and can also add new items in the sales table as wanted and the new in stock. But I can't add Stocks for rent items and also the combined Add Constraint with both tables at once don't work. I am not sure how to get it work that I can add my Items to the table. I always get the #1452 child table failure.

Maybe someone can help me an know how to handle it.

The result should be: I got to the table stock and hover over an ItemNo and when I click it I should be forwarded to table sales if ItemNo is from sales or rent if from rent. I am using Xampp phpmyadmin, MariaDB

Comment: SQL does not have conditional foreign keys - you could instead impose referential integrity through your app or a trigger. Perhaps reconsider your design - much of the data is the same for sales and rentals so maybe 1 table would do with a column to indicate if product is for sale or for rental and since rentals probably exist on a 1 to many basis a table for rental details only (item,rentstart,rentend,rentprice etc).

Answer (score 0):

So the error is `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` you should change values the `Sales` table on `ItemNo` change it before 1 to 1000 and more

your value is

```
INSERT INTO `Sales` (`ItemNo`, `Model`, `PurchasingPrice`,`ManufNo`, `LocNo`,`SuppNo`,`CatNo`,`Unitprice`) VALUES
(1,'Tieflader 18t',6969.84,4,1,6,2,9582.56),
(2,'Betonmischer-3m³',47829.00,3,2,3,3,82457.23),
(3,'Lastenkran 800kg',4129.00,2,2,2,3,8466.43),
(4,'Hubwagen,10m',9478.00,1,2,3,3,18457.84);
```

Change it to :

```
INSERT INTO `Sales` (`ItemNo`, `Model`, `PurchasingPrice`,`ManufNo`, `LocNo`,`SuppNo`,`CatNo`,`Unitprice`) VALUES
(1000,'Tieflader 18t',6969.84,4,1,6,2,9582.56),
(1001,'Betonmischer-3m³',47829.00,3,2,3,3,82457.23),
(1002,'Lastenkran 800kg',4129.00,2,2,2,3,8466.43),
(1003,'Hubwagen,10m',9478.00,1,2,3,3,18457.84);
```

Comment: thank you for your tip but I want separated numbers for sales which start at 1 and go max til 999 and rent should start at 1000, isn't this somehow possible?

Comment: It possible if you change the all record of ItemNo to start at 1 cause the data type of ItemNo INT and Primary it must be Unique, and will be error on one records if you put 1-4 jump to 1000